# Error: cannot open display firefox in linux

Tags: xorg, firefox, display

When I run firefox in bash, I am facing this : **Error: cannot open display** or **Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays**

I installed *xauth* , *xorg* etc. But did not resolve my problem.

I try in linux server that contains centos, debian, ubuntu. Firefox doesn't work with remote connection. I try different firefox version, I try different framework. Nothings change. `export DISPLAY=0:` not fixed, `DISPLAY=paxbox1.paxco.com:0.0 firefox &` not fixed , `xeyes -display paxbox1.paxco.com:0.0` too.

I want to web scraping with RSelenium. And RSelenium doesn't proper work that causes of the firefox
I struggle with this issue for two days.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do: it *sounds* like you want to display a *remote* instance of an X application on your *local* computer (via SSH?), in which case you will need a local X server and some kind of X forwarding.

Comment: Is this question still relevant?  If not, delete?

Comment: I am facing the same issue but the suggestions I've seen work for some people is the export DISPLAY needs to be :0 (export DISPLAY=:0 or :19, :1, :0.0 (not sure if its really different)).  Don't have a solution beyond that.